# Multiple embedded matplotlib canvases in pyqt change size on mouse over

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm trying to embed multiple matplotlib plots in a multi-column layout in a PyQt GUI. At first sight I succeed in setting up the layout as wanted but when moving the mouse over any of the canvasses they change size and 'flicker'. When pressing the zoom button on the toolbar this becomes more pronounced.

For each matplotlib canvas I have connected a toolbar. If I do not connect the toolbars the problem does not appear. I have tried arranging the toolbars and canvases several ways - with a QGridLayout or nested QVBoxLayouts and QHBoxLayouts. Either way the problem appears if there are plots along side each other. If I put all plots in a single column it does not.

I have tried this in Python 3.6 in Windows (Anaconda 5.0.1) with PyQt4 and Python 3.5.2 in Linux (KDE Neon 64 bit) and with both PyQt4 and PyQt5 (v. 5.7.1), matplotlib 1.5.1 but with the same result. I have also tried using add_axes instead of add_subplot. Can someone help me understand what is causing this or find some kind of workaround? I can not use matplotlib subplots.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        figure1 = Figure()
        figure2 = Figure()
        figure3 = Figure()
        figure4 = Figure()
        canvas1 = FigureCanvas(figure1)
        canvas2 = FigureCanvas(figure2)
        canvas3 = FigureCanvas(figure3)
        canvas4 = FigureCanvas(figure4)
        ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
        ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(111)
        ax3 = figure3.add_subplot(111)
        ax4 = figure4.add_subplot(111)

        toolbar1 = NavigationToolbar(canvas1, self)
        toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar(canvas2, self)
        toolbar3 = NavigationToolbar(canvas3, self)
        toolbar4 = NavigationToolbar(canvas4, self)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbar1,0,0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbar2,0,1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbar3,2,0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbar4,2,1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(canvas1,1,0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(canvas2,1,1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(canvas3,3,0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(canvas4,3,1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = Window()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm using pyqt4 on windows 8.1 with matplotlib 2.1. To me the plot looks and feels fine; I can't observe any flickering. What are the exact steps to reproduce the undesired behaviour and what exactly do you observe?

Comment: Mousing over plot-areas, the widths of the canvasses change. After sweeping over both/all plots the widths settle. Now I believe I understand the reason for this. When the window is initialised each canvas/toolbar is given a default size resulting in 50% for each column. But on mouse-over the toolbar shows display coordinates and this demands more space - thus the changing width. I would prefer to ensure that each column gets exactly 50% of the space but I haven't figured out how to do this. For now I initialise the window quite wide

Comment: I tried your code right now on Gentoo Linux (32bit) with matplotlib-1.4.3, pyqt-5.7.1 and python-3.4.5, and I cannot see the problems you are reporting.

Comment: I have newer or similar versions. I will update my question with the versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by:

```
toolbar1.setMinimumWidth(canvas1.width())
toolbar2.setMinimumWidth(canvas2.width())
toolbar3.setMinimumWidth(canvas3.width())
toolbar4.setMinimumWidth(canvas4.width())
```

The problem is when the toolbar becomes wider than the canvas.

Comment: This does work if the window is not resized. However, if I increase the window width to e.g. roughly 125% and then decrease it to about 110% then the problem reappears. The minimum width needs to be updated when canvas changes size. I have tried connecting self.resizeEvent to a method containing the above lines but as it is the minimumSize that is set this prevents shrinking the window again :-/